# How to show message when link empty

Tags: php, mysql

I created a simple detail page where the admin can see who is in the database... Now each person has a field resume where is a link that links to a resume in a file on the server... People do not have to send their resume with the form but still link appears by their name... How can I change this so when they don't ad a resume it will say there is no resume and when someone does add their resume it will link it to the file(which works)...

detail page:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// CREATE A CONNECTION WITH THE DATABASE
// CONNECTIE MAKEN MET DATABASE
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// SELECT TABLE NAMES FROM PERSON, ADDRESS AND CV WHERE address_id IS person_address and cv_id IS person_cv
// SELECTEER VAN TABEL PERSON, ADDRESS AND CV WAAR address_id  GELIJK IS AAN person_address EN cv_id AAN person_cv
$sql = "SELECT person_id, person_firstname, person_lastname, 
                 person_email, person_phonenumber,  
                 address_street,address_housenumber, 
                 address_city,address_state,address_zipcode, cv_path
          FROM person 
            inner join address on address.address_id = person.person_address 
            inner join cv on cv.cv_id = person.person_cv";

// EXECUTE QUERY IF THE RESULT BIGGER IS THAN ZERO
// VOER QUERY UIT ALS RESULTAAT GROTER IS DAN NUL
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

// ECHO A TABLE WITH VALUES 
// ECHO EEN TABEL MET ONDERSTAANDE WAARDES
echo "<form action='admin.php' method='post'>"; 
echo "<table border=0 align=right>
<tr>
<th>Voornaam</th>
<th>Achternaam</th>
<th>Straat</th>
<th>Huisnummer</th>
<th>Postcode</th>
<th>Stad</th>
<th>Provincie</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>Mobiel</th>
<th>cv</th>
<th>delete</th>
</tr>";

// LOOP THROUGH THE RESULTS AND OUTPUT THE RESULTS FOR EACH ROW
// GA DOOR RESULTATEN EN LAAT DE RESULTEN PER RIJ ZIEN
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["person_firstname"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["person_lastname"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["address_street"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["address_housenumber"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["address_zipcode"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["address_city"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["address_state"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["person_email"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row["person_phonenumber"] . "</td>";
     echo "<td><a href='http://localhost:8080/website/" . $row['cv_path'] . "'>cv file</a></td>";
     echo "<td><a href='delete.php?person_id=" . $row['person_id'] . "'>delete</a></td>";
     echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
  echo "</form>";
 }

  // IF THERE IS ZERO RESULT ECHO THIS
  // ALS WAARDE NUL IS LAAT DE ONDERSTAADE TEKST ZIEN
  else {
    echo "<p id='Tekst'>Er zijn geen deelnemers in de database gevonden.</p>";
  }
  // CLOSE CONNECTION
  // SLUIT CONNECTIE
  $conn->close();
 ?>
```

My resume upload (cv):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// CREATE A CONNECTION WITH THE DATABASE
// CONNECTIE MAKEN MET DATABASE
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// CHECK IF SUBMIT IS CLICKED
// CONTROLEER OF SUBMIT IS GEKLIKT
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$filetmp = $_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"];
$filename = $_FILES["cv"]["name"];
$filetype = $_FILES["cv"]["type"];
$filepath = "files/".$filename;

 move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);


// INSERT VALUES IN THE DATABASE
// VOEG WAARDES TOE IN DE DATABASE
$sql = "INSERT INTO cv (cv_name,cv_path,cv_type) VALUES ('$filename','$filepath','$filetype')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
// INSERT cv_id IN person_id
// VOEG cv_id TOE IN person_id
$cv = $conn->insert_id;
?>
```

Comment: Well, I'd say you simply test if `$row['cv_path']` contains something. Obviously assuming that the value only gets set when some document has been uploaded.

Comment: I tried few things however I can't get it work... New to PHP are their some tutorials or something I can watch to help me... I googled for 4 hours but still don't have anything good enough that fixes this problem.

Comment: You wrote above: "I created a simple detail page...". If you created that page then we assume you understand how it works. So you should be able to modify it. Using something like `empty($row['cv_path'])` you can decide if you execute that line or something else: `echo "<td><a href='http://localhost:8080/website/" . $row['cv_path'] . "'>cv file</a></td>";`.

Comment: Well the main problem I am having is... When someone doesn't send their resume it will create a row for their resume in PhpMyAdmin with the path to files/ because this is the path where I save all the files. So when clicking on the link going to the file it will open the directory in the browers with all the files...

Comment: quite a few things wrong in your code and some of it will not fire up at all. check for errors

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the default constraint to "No Resume".

While creating the table just make sure the default value for the cv is set to "No resume", and when you need to call for the details, just check if the field has a "No resume" value, if it doesn't, just this-

```
<?php //select * from the table first
if(cvPath=="No resume") { echo "No resume";} else echo 
"<a href=/"cvlink/">Resume</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside while

you are doing this

```
 echo "<td><a href='http://localhost:8080/website/" . $row['cv_path'] . "'>cv file</a></td>";
```

try this

```
$path = "http://localhost:8080/website/" . $row['cv_path'];
if(!empty($row['cv_path']) && file_exists($path)){
     echo "<td><a href='$path'>cv file</a></td>";
}
else{
     echo "<td>No Resume</td>";
}
```

Comment: It's showing No Resume by all the persons in the table who do have their resume uploaded

Comment: In a comment above I said that a row in my phpmyadmin is created even if there is no resume uploaded... The cv_path is only files/ because this is the file where all the resumes are stored.

Comment: Is there a way to change my upload like when is empty cv_name and path say no resume or something